# How do you make text aligned with the cell below it with css?

Tags: html, css

I'm designing an email and I'm not sure how to make text aligned with the rows below it. I want the "Our Weather Experts" and "ARE LOOKING OUT FOR YOU." to stretch across the table and be flush with the rows below it that includes the paragraph and learn more button. I tried using letter spacing and different sorts of padding, but is this even possible?

It's supposed to look like this:

[image]

I also tried to get the "Our Weather Experts" line to be skinny text, but the font-weight: lighter attribute doesn't seem to be working either.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style type="text/css">

    .borderbottom {border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;}
    .innerpadding {padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;}

    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
    .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
    body, table, td, a{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
    table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
    img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;} /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */

    /* RESET STYLES */
    body{margin:0; padding:0;}
    img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
    table{border-collapse:collapse !important;}
    body{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    .appleBody a {color:#68440a; text-decoration: none;} 
    .appleFooter a {color:#999999; text-decoration: none;} 


</style>
</head>
<body yahoo="fix" style="margin: 0; padding: 0; ">
<table class="container" width="640" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0 auto; padding: 0;">
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
            <div class="mobile-only" style="text-indent: -99999em; display: none; height: 0; width: 0; overflow: hidden; max-height: 0;">
                <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Header-Mobile-320x159.jpgg" border="0">
            </div>
            <div class="no-mobile">
                <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Header-Desktop-640x220.jpg" border="0">
            </div>
     </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding:30px;" >
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="letter-spacing: 3px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:43px; color: #002663">
                OUR WEATHER EXPERTS
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="letter-spacing: 3px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:36px; color: #002663">
                <strong>ARE LOOKING OUT FOR YOU.</strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                            <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#666666; line-height:20px; padding:20px 35px 25px 0px;" align="left" class="borderbottom">
                            Your area is likely to receive severe storms in the upcoming months. We've prepared information and tips to help protect you and your loved ones this season.
                            </td>
                            <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; vertical-align:top; padding: 20px 0px 30px 0px"; align="left" class="borderbottom">
                                <a href="#"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Button-Learn-More-139x38.jpg" style="display:block;" width="139" height="38"></a>
                            </td>                                                       
                        </tr>
        </table>
    </td> 
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is

```
text-align:justify;
```

but with only one line of text it gets a bit messy.

You need to add an empty container with a width of 100% to push the text to the end.

```
<span style="display:inline-block;width:100%;"></span>
```

Then it will add extra space below the text so you need to adjust the line-heights.

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/y7vp8oz0/

Comment: Thank you so much! This was racking my brain all day!